# How to create state_pressed effect that reduces shadow and moves content (with layer lists)?

Tags: android, android-layout, layer-list

I have a custom `box_background.xml` drawable which should add some decorations to a box (e.g. a RelativeLayout):

- A small border (2dp)
- A shadow (8dp), to the left and bottom

When pressed, the view should change a little:

- The shadow is smaller (say, 4dp)
- The content of the box moves slightly to the left & bottom (i.e. "towards the shadow")
- (2dp border remains the same, but of course it still has to wrap the moved content nicely.)

By itself, `box_background_normal` works as intended (when `box_background_state_pressed` is commented out from the selector). What I don't understand: if `box_background_state_pressed` contains an item with padding (see the XML below), that padding affects the box even when it is **not** pressed.

Maybe `<padding>` just can't be used to achieve this kind of "state pressed" functionality...?

My specific questions:

- Why on earth does padding in `box_background_state_pressed` affect the
  view when it is **not** pressed?
- How can I achieve the kind of "state pressed" effect I described above?

[image]
Example 1: **not pressed** state when `box_background_state_pressed` is not in use at all (commented out from the selector): border, shadow and content are ok.

[image]
Example 2: **not pressed** state when `box_background_state_pressed` is in use. This is broken; the bigger padding in `box_background_state_pressed` affects the content even though the box is not pressed.

Android API level 18. Test device: Nexus 7 (2013).

`box_background.xml`:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/box_background_state_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/box_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

`box_background_normal.xml`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="8dp" android:right="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#33000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="8dp" android:left="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">    
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF22BB00" />    
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:right="2dp"
                android:top="2dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

`box_background_state_pressed.xml` (you could probably do this with less than 3 layers; I'm just experimenting) :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="4dp" android:right="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#33000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFF6677" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
            <padding
                android:left="2dp"
                android:bottom="2dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

(Green and pink borders just for debugging reasons; normally it would be black.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue and just came across the existence of the selector property [android:variablePadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#attr_android%3avariablePadding).  It won't solve my problem, since I'm getting my images on the fly, but you might want to try adding that property to your selector nodes.